# Compare last day total consumption for Kafka consumer in Grafana

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana

I am new to this topic.

I have find the total consumption for Kafka consumer for a particular topic and displayed over my Grafana dashboard using below query.

> kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total{job="$application",
>   instance="$instance", client_id=~"$client_id", topic=~"$topic"}

Now I have to put alert on same/or different graph, to compare last day total consumption for specific time to till day specific time consumption.

Example : Suppose for today the total consumption between time 16:00 to 16:05 is 10K messages, and it was around 12K yesterday for same time ie, 16:00 - 16:05. This shows the drop of 2K messages in same time compare to yesterday. So I want to put alert on it.

How do I achieve it? Kindly help in with the query or some appropriate link for the same.

Thanks in advance for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, but the fact that you are consuming 2K messages less than yesterday on a given time don't necessarily means that something went wrong with your consumer.
It's really depends on your traffic patterns - maybe you are receiving less messages?

If you are trying to understand if you are receiving less data than yesterday, you can monitor `BytesInPerSec` and `MessagesInPerSec`.

A proper way to monitor and alert on consumer related issues might be lag monitoring.
Lag basically indicates how far behind your application is in processing real-time data.

> When consuming messages from Kafka it is common practice to use a consumer group.
>   Consumer group lag is the difference between the last produced message (the latest message available) and the last committed message (the last processed or read message) of a partition.  For example, if there are 130 total messages in a partition and we’ve committed up to 100, then the consumer group lag for that partition is 30 messages/offsets.

[source](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/monitor-kafka-consumer-group-latency-with-kafka-lag-exporter)

There are few options out there - you can try [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow), [Lightbend](https://github.com/lightbend/kafka-lag-exporter) or [Remora](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora).
You can read more about this topic in [Lightbend post](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/monitor-kafka-consumer-group-latency-with-kafka-lag-exporter) or in [Sematext post](https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-consumer-lag-offsets-monitoring/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will update upon status once go through the solution.